# .net or other extension in Raspberry Pi hostname

Tags: networking, pi-4

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

i saw on Jeff Geerling's site his Raspberry Pi had a hostname ending with .net, i want to have this too, since it would be prettier to access my Raspberry Pi via 'hostname.net' instead of 'hostname/' or 'hostname.local'.

How can this be done?

Comment: please edit your question with a link to the article you are asking about

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you're asking. But since you've not given any relevant information in your question (other than your desire for ***pretty*** (which is fine AFAIC), it's very difficult to know what solution would suit you best. IOW, we **invest time** in these answers, but your question doesn't provide much basis that this is a good investment; this is my opinion - others will see it differently perhaps.

So I don't have an *answer* here, but only a few brief *suggestions*:

1. If your RPi is running a *default* setup, it uses a program called `avahi` to perform a *multicast DNS*. This is sometimes called "Zero Configuration Networking" - because you don't have to do **anything** in a typical situation. You can learn more about this by searching for `avahi` & reading.
2. You should also search & read (e.g. [example search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=avahi+hostnames+%26+domain+names&atb=v278-1&ia=web). Here's a [good question with several answers you may find useful](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname).
3. If you'd spent some of **your time** doing your homework, your question might seem a more compelling investment... good for you, and good for us!
4. When people ask questions here about something they've read in a blog or tutorial, I often wonder why they didn't ask the **author** of that 'blog/tutorial/how-to' the question they ask here. After all, the author wrote the piece, and you wouldn't need to bother with pesky things like references and URLs, or explaining the context of your question. Please know that we do appreciate good questions here, but a good question must be supported by enough context to support a good answer.
5. All of that said, if you consult `man avahi-daemon.conf`, you will find this passage:

> domain-name= Set the default domain name avahi-daemon tries to register its host name and services on the LAN in. If omitted defaults to ".local".

And so you **may** be able to configure the `avahi` service to default to `.net` instead of `.local` (the default). However, this **may** create issues because `.net` is one of the [*original* top-level Internet domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). I say **"may"** because I'm not persuaded by your question to invest more time exploring this potential issue... *perhaps Jeff Geerling didn't either, but maybe he should have if he reccomended it*. Anyway, that's enough on this question as it now needs only a single additional vote to be **closed**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use **no extension** - only the hostname:

1. Verify you have the hostname you want defined in `/etc/hostname`; e.g. in my case I use names like `raspberrypi4b` so I know *which* pi.
2. Edit the file `/etc/hosts`:

```bash
$ nano /etc/hosts
```

You should see something very much like this - except the last line (`127.0.1.1`) may be different or missing entirely:

> 127.0.0.1  localhost
> ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
> ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
> ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
> 127.0.1.1   raspberrypi4b raspberrypi4b.local

Use your editor to specify your "bare" hostname (`raspberrypi4b` in this case), and your hostname.local; yes, two names. Save your changes, exit the editor, and `reboot`. As `avahi` disseminates its "DNS" information through a *chatty* process, it may take a few minutes before your `raspberrypi4b` name is cast about to the other network participants, but soon afterwards, you should be able to do this (for example):

```
seamus@Dung-Pro ~ % ssh pi@raspberrypi4b
Nothing to say... (via /etc/issue.net)Linux raspberrypi4b 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l
Current Date & Time: Tue Feb 21 01:24:25 UTC 2023
this is /etc/motd - there's nothing here!
No mail.
Last login: Mon Feb 20 23:37:48 2023 from 192.168.1.178
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $
```

IOW, I am in the `bash` shell on my RPi 4B.

N.B.: This will work on Linux & MacOS, but may not work on Windows without installation of competent software.